# Adding text-box to table columns conditionally

Tags: jquery, html, textbox, html-table, toggle

I have a table in which I have three columns, namely `type`, `1st type`, `2nd type`. In `type` I have a button which toggles between two values, `Db` and `Cr`. I want to add a text box to column `1st type` if the button's value is `Db` and add text box to column `2nd type` if the button's value is `Cr`. I have tried something, but it is not giving me the desired result.

Here is my code:

```
$(".pushme").click(function () {
    $(this).text(function(i, v){
       return v === 'Db' ? 'Cr' : 'Db'
    })
});

$(function(){
    if($(".pushme").value="Db"){
        $("#D-amt").append('<input type="text" name="db" />');
    }
    else{
        $("#C-amt").append('<input type="text" name="cr" />');
    }
});
```

```html
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><button class='pushme'>Click me</button></td>
        <td id="D-amt"></td>
        <td id="C-amt"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```js
$(function(){
 $('button').on('click', function() {
   var elem = $(this),
     tds = elem.closest('td').nextUntil('tr');
    tds.html('');
   if( $(this).text() == 'Db' ) {
     $(this).text('Cr');
        tds.eq(0).html('<input type="text" name="db" />');
    }
    else {
     $(this).text('Db');
        tds.eq(1).html('<input type="text" name="cr" />');    
    }
  })  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<thead>
  <tr><td>Type</td><td>Type 1</td><td>Type 2</td></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><button>Db</button></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><button>Db</button></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><button>Db</button></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: But can u let me know what was wrong with my code?@LinkinTED

Comment: In your if statement you use .value(), it's however the .text() that you change. Further would this only work on one row. If you add more, you'll need more functions. My code is dynamic and handles all buttons.